# How can one fetch subtotal in relation to a group by from an outer query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a simple query,  where I would like to display for past 7 days, grouped by hour from a table `apiRequest`: *The count of request having a transaction vs the count of those having no transaction.*

I tried two different approaches but both failed. The first column displays fine, it is the second one that is problematic:

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| Date         | Time        | Total Requests     | no trans.       |
+--------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| January 20th | 2:00-3:00   |                 44 |               0 |
| January 20th | 3:00-4:00   |                 32 |               0 |
| January 20th | 5:00-6:00   |                 51 |               0 |
| January 20th | 6:00-7:00   |                 18 |               0 |
```

First approach was with a subquery, that nearly worked but I could not get the `WHERE accountDetails NOT LIKE "%Transactions\":[{%"` to work.

Second query was with an `inner join`, but could not manage to get the group by to work as expected for second column.

```
--  Two column table that displays number of requests for past seven days, grouped by hour of the day
-- First try, with subquery - the second column does not show result


--  Col 1 - Shows count of requests with transactions, 
--  Col 2 - count of requests without transactions
--  for every hour of the day in past seven days
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.created, "%M %D") Date,
       CONCAT(HOUR(a.created), ':00-', HOUR(a.created)+1, ':00') Time,
       count(a.`RequestId`) as "Total Requests",
         (select count(a2.`RequestId`) FROM apiRequest a2 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(f.created,"%Y %M %D %H") = DATE_FORMAT(a2.created, "%M %D %H")) "IBV's no trans."
        FROM apiRequest a
   WHERE a.created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day
     AND a.RequestId IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.created, "%M %D %H");


-- Second try, with inner join - group by does not work
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.created, "%M %D"),
       CONCAT(HOUR(a.created), ':00-', HOUR(f.created)+1, ':00') AS Hours,
       count(a.`RequestId`) as "Total requests",
       f2.ibvsNoTrans
        FROM apiRequest a
        INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(RequestId) ApiNoTrans FROM ApiRequest WHERE accountDetails NOT LIKE "%Transactions\":[{%" GROUP BY date_format(apiRequest.created, "%Y %M")) f2
           WHERE a.created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day
     AND a.RequestId IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY YEAR(a.created), MONTH(a.created), DAY(a.created), HOUR(a.created), Hours;
```

I am quite certain I am close to the goal but missing a detail. 
I feel this should be simpler, what is the proper approach, and is there a more optimal manner to match on dates / hours than what I have?

Comment: Please have a look at: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Comment: More compact:  `GROUP BY LEFT(a.created, 13), hours`

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the missing data, first you need to create a table with all the hours.  Then `LEFT JOIN` from that table to your table.

You may also need a `COALESCE(..., 0)` to turn `NULL` into `0`.